# Confuse about Promises/A pattern in jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise

Recently I read an [article](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) about drawback in early jQuery Promises/A pattern:

> Libraries like jQuery (before 1.8) don't do this: they simply mutate
>   the state of the existing promise. That means if you give a promise
>   out to multiple consumers, they can interfere with its state. To
>   realize how ridiculous that is, consider the synchronous parallel: if
>   you gave out a function's return value to two people, and one of them
>   could somehow change it into a thrown exception!

I want to use code to achieve the drawback, I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var promise = $.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");

    var promise1 = promise.then(function (result) {
        return "Hello";
    });

    promise1.then(function (result) {
        console.log("in promise1 ------>", result.length);
    })

    var promise2 = promise.then(function (result) {
        return "World";
    })

    promise2.then(function (result) {
        console.log("in promise2 ------>", result.length);
    })
</script>
</head>
...
```

it seems doesn't work, how can I achieve the situation as the article described above?

Comment: What does "achieve the drawback" mean?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: I want to write a demo, which could show how `...they simply mutate the state of the existing promise...`

Comment: So you want to write some code that demonstrates a shortcoming in a superseded version of jQuery. Do you not think your time could be better spent?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: Actually I don't quite understand the shortcoming, I think wrting a demo could help me understand it, and avoid making this kind of mistake in future days

Comment: But you aren't likely to make this sort of mistake. (a) you're not about to use jQuery <1.8 and (b) you're not about to write a Promises/A implementation of your own ..... are you?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: In fact I'm glad to have a try...

Answer (score 1):

Well something like this will not work before 1.8, with `.then` - only with `.pipe`:

```
function doStuff() {
  promptAsync("What url you want to fetch?").then(function (url) {
    return $.get(url)
  }).then(function (contents) {
    return confirmAsync("Here are the contents " + contents + ". Is this ok?")
  }).then(function (confirmation) {
    if (!confirmation) {
      return doStuff();
    }
    return alertAsync("I am glad you are happy with these results");
  });
}
```

This parallels the sync equivalent:

```
function doStuff() {
  var url = prompt("What url you want to fetch?");
  var contents = $.get(url);
  var confirmation = confirm("Here are the contents " + contents + ". Is this ok?");
  if (!confirmation) {
    doStuff();
  } else {
    alert("I am glad you are happy with these results");
  }
}
```

Of course, even after 1.8, any error thrown will not be available from promise `.fail` but instead crashes your page.